# kivy: fixed layout with absolute positioning only

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I try to make a window with kivy. Everything should be positioned absolute.
However I struggle with simple things like adding a label at a certain position because `position: 5, 5` just gets ignored.

So how to I layout a Window where I can place everything at a defined location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root witget should be either a `Screen`, `FloatLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. This will allow you to set an absolute `pos` attribute for its children.

Comment: @Fuzzyma [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos)